# How to catch and respond to a scene addition event?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

My add-on uses a number of dynamically registered panels, created and configured per scene. It needs to refresh/rebuild itself whenever the scene changes to represent the data in the active scene. I'm using a msgbus subscription upon `bpy.types.Window.scene` to respond to scene switches by destroying/rebuilding the UI, but this doesn't catch scene creation/deletion events.

In order to do that I've added an app handler for `depsgraph_update_post`, which fires for scene deletion events but unfortunately is not triggered when a new scene is created. When a new scene is added my UI is left in it's previous, now incorrect state, until the user does something to trigger a depsgraph update and my UI rebuilding code is executed. I've enabled various debug options in the console and monitored output during scene changes to try and find something I can hook into and leverage but I'm coming up empty handed. I'd rather not implement a recurrent timer-based check of the current scene to trigger a UI update, but that's what I'm now faced with.

Does anyone have any ideas or advice for use of msgbus and/or app handlers that would allow me to respond to scene creation events in a timely manner? Thanks in advance for your help, I am constantly amazed by this ingenuity, patience, and generosity of this community. Kudos!

*Edited, adding context below:*

The number of panels in the sidebar is determined by the user clicking Add/Remove operators in a static master panel. The number and configuration of these dynamic panels in a scene is stored in a property group in the scene. When the active scene changes the add-on destroys/unregisters the UI panels for the previously active scene, and creates/registers new panels according to the panel config of the newly active scene. It's trying to replicate the behaviour of the modifier stack, where selecting a new object destroys/creates modifier sub-panels according to object selection. Except instead of modifiers on objects, I'm doing this with panels per scene. This works nicely when switching back and forth between existing scenes, and it can catch the deletion of an existing scene by using the depsgraph update to trigger a UI refresh, but when a new scene is created it don't have any means of responding to this until the user does something like add/move an object to trigger a depsgraph update.

Comment: What is the bl_context of your addon? It should draw or poll if the scene changes, i think.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13569

Comment: @lemon The add-on creates panels in the 3D view sidebar at runtime by registering panels with `bl_context = 'objectmode'`  sub-classed from an unregistered 'template' panel

Comment: @Daurte Thanks, but my question wasn't about custom event handling. Put simply, why isn't the dependency graph update triggered when a scene is added? I believe the depsgraph_build handler used to be exposed in a previous version of blender, and that would have been perfect for my use case, but that's not available. Do you have any constructive advice?

Comment: This is super hacky and not a direct answer to your question, but I've worked around similar things in the past by registering more panels than I need, and using the `poll` method to hide the extras. The other thing I've done, as you mentioned, is using a timer. Unfortunately I've never worked with scene handlers so I can't offer anything better.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, appreciate the input. I've done something similar in other projects with pooled resources being setup in bulk beforehand and assigned/released dynamically upon demand. In this use case leveraging poll methods to show/suppress panels. But then we're into the complexity of pool management and operator reassignment(?!). There used to be exposed handlers for scene_update and depsgraph_build events in previous version of the API so why these are no longer available and now require hacks on top of workarounds on top of kludges escapes me. Meh! Thanks for your encouragement anyway! :)

Comment: Quentin, what proposed @ChrisHayes works. Don't you have some scene properties to rely on in order to trigerr a timer?

Comment: @lemon Yes, I'll throw together a recurring timer check against scene properties to trigger UI refreshes. I'd prefer something more aligned with the handler and msgbus systems but at least I know that it's not failing because of my own ignorance. Which makes a nice change for me. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @QuentinWalker, you can fire a timer only once from poll, just in order to allow your code to modify the scene as you need. So no recurrent timer calls.